# jinja2 for loop on dropdown menu

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am currently working on a flask project and was thinking it should be possible to make my html dropdown filter list dryer, instead of 10 anchor tags I could use a for loop.  So I made a list called category_list with all the categories and pass that to my template to iterate over.

So instead of 10..

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('course', course='Starter') }}">Starter</a>
```

I'm trying the following..

```
{% for item in category_list %}
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('course', course='[item]') }}">{{ item }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The part i'm unsure about is **course='[item]'**

The dropdown names are appearing fine but my url is not being generated, any tips would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your *anchor tags should redirect to your `course` route* and that you want to *set the `course` variable appropriately based on the anchor tag selected*. The solution would be to just reference your `item` variable directly within your `url_for(...)` method. Remember as you're looping through your `category_list` each `item` is just a single element contained within your `category_list`. Maybe you could try something along the lines of:

```
{% for item in category_list %}
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('course', course=item) }}">{{ item }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that fixes my problem.  Thanks a million!!  Al